# Running several web applications from a single domain name on IIS

Tags: iis, hosting, web-hosting

Supposing I have my main asp.net website hosted at domain.com.

Is it possible to install another website (web app) so that it is accessible via "subfolder": http://www.domain.com/second-app ?

Is there a restriction on what technology the second app can be? Can it be PHP, even though the main site is asp.net?

To make it clearer, as an example:
Main website: http://www.domain.com/
Then I want to install one of the wiki-engines so that it will be accessible like so: http://www.domain.com/wiki
From the technical IIS point of view these 2 will be different websites.

So, is such a setup possible? If so, how? Any web.config settings one should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is quite common. The second app can be in any language (but since it's IIS it will inherit the "Web.config" settings under the parent app.)

You just have to make sure you install PHP for IIS: https://php.iis.net/

So in IIS to accomplish this.

1. You will create a site "domain.com"
2. Right click on that site and click "Add Application"

It's that simple.